# Can't create an SQL Table in Python using input as name

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a little issue with my python code. I want to take the input from user and based on that create an SQL table with that name. I take the input in table_name variable and want to do it so:

```
sql = "CREATE TABLE %s" % table_name
cur.execute(sql)
```

Let's say I run it with input "books". I get this error:

> File "XXX", line 55, in FUNCTIONNAME
>  cur.execute(sql)
>   sqlite3.OperationalError: near "books": syntax error

Any ideas on what is wrong? I googled it and above code should be OK, but it isn't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's most probably cause you are not passing the table definition (column names and their type , size). What I see from posted code is that you are passing only table name and so your query becomes below which is totally wrong

```
CREATE TABLE books
```

Comment: Ok, you are right. I wanted to make it without any columns (on purpose), but didn't realise that is nercessary. thank's for help.